# Programming fundas

Tags: sql, sas

Would some one suggest me the best method to start learning the fundas of programming.
I would be involved in SQL and SAS related technologies involving databases.

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best advice on learning to program:  Pick a project and start working on it.  Things will make a lot more sense when you try to use them.  You don't have to finish even.  Don't worry about the end result.  You'll learn through the process.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is an easier one to tackle. You can download a small database (mysql or oracle express) and begin working. Test and play and read until you get the hang of it. There are many articles available to give guidance. Just Google.

SAS on the other hand is a bit more difficult. You can't get your hands on the software unless your employer has a copy or you purchase a user copy from your university or from SAS. I would suggest taking a class from SAS. They offer SAS Essentials 1 for beginners. Great class, not cheap.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can give you is to get books on the subject and maybe try find somebody in your area you can learn from or work with to gain some knowledge. Otherwise find articles and blogs relating to SQL and SAS.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

both sql and sas are not good for learning programming fundamentals, because they are not typical programming languages. Learn C# or Java for system development, or Python or Ruby for scripting. Most undergraduate programming courses will also include some kind of functional programming languages.

once you have some fundamentals under your belt, sql itself can be learned in a very short time. in the class I took on database systems, the professor gave only two one-hour lectures on sql.

sas has a steep learning curve, because it is a system, not a language. In terms of languages, in fact, some might say that it has 30 or more different "languages" in it.